# Simliest and pythonic way to Serialize/Deserialize Object <->dict <-> JSON in Python3.5+

Tags: serialization, python-3.6

I am new to python, and I know there are many answers, but most of the use the `__dict__` which is **not present** in **Python3** any more.

Let's say I have object:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, f1, f2):
    self.f1 = f1
    self.f2 = f2
```

now the f2 is another object:

```
class F2(object):
  def __init__(self, f21, f22):
    self.f21 = f21
    self.f22 = f22
```

So `A` object is complex object. What is the simpliest way to:

- serialize `A` to `dict` and than to `json`.
- and then to deserialize it back from `json` -> `A`

all in Python 3.5+ and *possibly* without additional imports as our internal company nexus is limited.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pickle
import base64
import json


class A(object):
  def __init__(self, f1, f2):
    self.f1 = f1
    self.f2 = f2

a = pickle.dumps(A, 3)
j = base64.b64encode(a).decode('utf-8')
x = json.dumps([j])
print(a)
print(j)
print(x)
# output:
# b'\x80\x03c__main__\nA\nq\x00.'
# gANjX19tYWluX18KQQpxAC4=
# ["gANjX19tYWluX18KQQpxAC4="]
```

Deserialization would be the inverse; `json.loads`, `string.encode` `base64.b64decode`, `pickle.loads`.